# Replace youtube embed in wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, filters

I am using this code to replace youtube video:

```
add_filter('embed_oembed_html', 'foo_embed_oembed_html', 99, 4);
add_filter('video_embed_html', 'foo_embed_oembed_html');

function foo_embed_oembed_html( $cache, $url, $attr, $post_ID ) {

    if ( false !== strpos( $url, 'youtube' ) ) {
    
        if ( preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=v\/)[^&\n]+(?=\?)|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+|(?<=youtu.be/)[^&\n]+#", $url, $matches)) {

               // return my shortcode

        }
}
```

This works well with this example:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/LPVKH11pA8s
```

But the function foo_embed_oembed_html is not even called if I use this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/LPVKH11pA8s?rel=0
```

What would be the reason?